# Unable to get list "Calendar" list in feature while creating site

Tags: feature, calendar, feature-activation, provisioning, sharepoint-calendar

I want to create custom calendar list programatically.

```
SPListTemplate template = web.ListTemplates["Calendar"];
var newListID = web.Lists.Add(fromTitle, description, template);
```

But i cannot do this because of out of range exception! Calendar template cannot be found!

But when site is created i can see Calendar template in list of templates!

Also those two features is activated before my code

```
public Guid GroupWorkLists = new Guid("9c03e124-eef7-4dc6-b5eb-86ccd207cb87");

public Guid TeamCollaborationLists = new Guid("00bfea71-4ea5-48d4-a4ad-7ea5c011abe5");
```

What i am doing wrong and why i cannot get calendar list template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `web.ListTemplates["Events"]` or `web.ListTemplates[106]`.

[SPListTemplateType enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplatetype.aspx)